# Setting Zoom on UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview, zooming

I am using the following code to load the webpage from the launch of the app and to zoom and resize when the view appears.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.pdf"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0]];


}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [webView.scrollView setZoomScale:2.0 animated:YES];
  [webView.scrollView setBounds:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 367)];

    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

When I first click on that view, it zooms in, but has not moved to the 320, 0 area.  If I click to a different view and then go back, it will then zoom and move to the correct bounds.  Any idea why this is not working properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try add this code to your viewWillAppear:

```
[webView.scrollView setContentOffest:CGPointMake(320,0)];
```

I dont promise that its help. Comment, if it don't help.